# The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."}

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

I'm using VS2010, C#, .net, and xmlWriter to create xml documents to HL7 CAT-1 specification.  There is an attribute, 'sdtc:ValueSet' that must be created in the document.  I am unable to write this attribute name, due to invalid character ":".

Here is the actual line of code:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("sdtc:valueSet", "OID value");
```

Does anyone have a solution for creating the attribute, as shown?

Continuing to research, but decided to post this question in hopes of quickly finding a solution.

This question was flagged as a duplicate, incorrectly I am arguing.  Existing responses referenced writing an element, or using LINQ.  The problem explicitly states Attribute, using xmlWriter.   One responder suggested using an overloaded WriteAttributeString method, which 
solved the problem.

Comment: You're not very good at research. I found a duplicate simply by searching on your title.

Answer (score 5):

You're using the wrong overload of the [WriteAttributeString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0by65955.aspx). Use [the one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z46xs1.aspx) that allows you to specify a prefix and an XML namespace:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("sdtc", "valueSet", "urn:hl7-org:sdtc", "OID value");
```